# How to use timber.RightDrawer.open(); in custom add to cart success to open drawer?

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, timber

I am using add to cart with custom ajax code and its working fine, problem is I need to open cart drawer on success function by using timber.RightDrawer.open(); 
For now I am using "js-drawer-open-right" class in form but its open drawer same time when click on add to cart button. I need to open drawer on success of add to cart.

My Ajax code is:

```
                function addItem(button) {
                var postData = $(button).closest('.add-to-cart').serialize();
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/cart/add.js',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: postData,
                    success: addToCartOk,
                    error: addToCartFail
                  });
                }
                function addToCartOk(product) {
                //Want to open drawer here on success
                  timber.RightDrawer.open();
                }
                function addToCartFail(obj, status) {
                }
```

My form is:

Here you can check Add to Cart https://soft-theme.myshopify.com/collections/all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find out different and very easy solution for this as compare to timber.RightDrawer.open();

I have clicked "js-drawer-open-right" with jQuery in success function and removed that class from form which I have placed before.

The success function now is:

```
         function addToCartOk(product) {
            //drawer open here by click on that class on success
              jQuery('.js-drawer-open-right').click();
            }
```

Its worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

@barjinder solution but cleaner:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-to-cart-button", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(cart) {
            jQuery('.js-drawer-open-right').click();
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            alert("An error occurred: can't reach server");
        },
    });
});
```

You can use the below form

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="add-to-cart-button">
        Add to cart
    </button>
</form>
```